# Вывод переменных/констант из таблицы

Tags: php, переменные, mysql

Приветствую!

В таблице имеются записи вида:

```
id|name
--|--------
1 |VARIABLE
```

Примерно так вывожу записи:

```
define('VARIABLE','Текст');
...
$result = $db->select(DB_MODULES_MENU);
foreach($result as $row)
{
echo $row['name']) \\ выведет VARIABLE
}
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы отображалось значение константы, в данном случае "Текст"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constant($row['name']);`

Comment: constant() - отличное решение, очень выручили!